# R - How to display X axis values on barplot from data frame

Tags: r, bar-chart

I have a data Frame that looks like the following,

```
str(data2)
'data.frame':   516 obs. of  2 variables:
 $ Jobs      : num  2 1 5 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
 $ Time         : chr  "06:00" "06:01" "06:02" "06:04" ...
```

I am trying to create a barplot from this data Frame.

If I run,

```
barplot(data2$Jobs,
    col="orange", 
    xlab="Time of Day", 
    ylab="Files With Jobs", 
    main="Jobs by Time of Day Received")
```

This is fine, and gives me the barPlot, but the X axis is blank. I need to have the `Time` column showing on the X Axis.

I tried,

```
barplot(data2$Time,data2$Jobs,
    col="orange", 
    xlab="Time of Day", 
    ylab="Files With Jobs", 
    main="Jobs by Time of Day Received")
```

But this gives me,

> Error in -0.01 * height : non-numeric argument to binary operator

What is the correct way to do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the `names.arg` argument to `barplot`:

```
barplot(data2$Jobs, 
        names.arg=data2$Time,
        col="orange", 
        xlab="Time of Day", 
        ylab="Files With Jobs", 
        main="Jobs by Time of Day")
```

Answer (score 2):

You can also use `ggplot`:

```
data<- data.frame(jobs=c(2, 1, 5, 0), Time=c("06:00", "06:01", "06:02", "06:04"))
data$Time <-  strptime(data$Time, format="%H:%M")

ggplot(data=data,aes(x=Time,y=jobs)) + 
  geom_bar( stat="identity", colour = "brown1", size = 1.5)+
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 90,hjust=1,vjust=0.3))+
  xlab("Time of Day") +
  ylab("Files With Jobs")
```

[image]